# SQL insert year wise rows in child table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in my SQL database: Parent and Child
Parent's primary key is Child's foreign key - ID

I have data in Parent but Child is empty. I need to fill the Child table as mentioned below:

Parent:

```
ID  StartYear  EndYear   Capacity
1     2016      2020       2.0
2     2018      2021       3.5
```

Child:

```
ID  Year   Capacity
1   2016     2.0
1   2017     2.0
1   2018     2.0
1   2019     2.0
1   2020     2.0
2   2018     3.5
2   2019     3.5
2   2020     3.5
2   2021     3.5
```

I can use either a query or a procedure to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to join the table Parent:

```
declare @maxendyear int = (select max(endyear) from parent);
with years AS (
  select min(startyear) year from parent 
  union all
  select year + 1 FROM years where year + 1 <= @maxendyear
)
insert into child (id, year, capacity)
select 
  p.id, y.year, p.capacity
from parent p inner join years y
on y.year between p.startyear and p.endyear
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5a412515d47060b725221b3711bb0c9).
If the data type of the years columns is varchar change to this:

```
declare @maxendyear int = cast((select max(endyear) from parent) as int);
with years AS (
  select cast(min(startyear) as int) year from parent 
  union all
  select year + 1 FROM years where year + 1 <= @maxendyear
)
insert into child (id, year, capacity)
select 
  p.id, y.year, coalesce(p.capacity, 0)
from parent p inner join years y
on y.year between p.startyear and p.endyear
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c304b9ce7eaa93c5f5f792fb3d9ed4fe).
Results:

```
> ID | Year | Capacity
> -: | ---: | -------:
>  1 | 2016 |        2
>  1 | 2017 |        2
>  1 | 2018 |        2
>  1 | 2019 |        2
>  1 | 2020 |        2
>  2 | 2018 |      3.5
>  2 | 2019 |      3.5
>  2 | 2020 |      3.5
>  2 | 2021 |      3.5
```

Comment: Demo is working fine. In my case it is giving an error:
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "year" of recursive query "years".

I guess something to do with the datatype of the year column

Comment: What is the data type of the columns startyear and endyear?

Comment: Ya, that error is resolved. Thanks.
Now is says: Cannot insert the value NULL into column Capacity.
Since the column in the child doesn't take NULL. Is there a way I can put 0 in child when the value in parent is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join` to get the values you want:

```
select c.*, p.capacity
from child c join
     parent p
     on c.id = p.id and
        c.year between p.startyear and p.endyear;
```

EDIT:

I think you might want to generate *all* the rows in the `child` table.  If so you can use a recursive CTE depending on database:

```
with cte as (
      select id, startyear as year, capacity, endyear
      from parent
      union all
      select id, year + 1, capacity, endyear
      from cte
      where year < endyear
     )
select id, year, capacity
from cte
order by id, year;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c0d74baee6ea099c2b8a7ceaf1ff8f7) is a db<>fiddle.

You can also use a table of numbers or derived table and `join`:

```
select p.id, (p.startyear + n.n) as year, p.capacity
from parent p join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
      select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ) n
     on p.startyear + n.n <= p.endyear
;
```

Comment: I am looking to insert values in the child table by selecting rows from parent table.

Comment: I tried the last one and it's working. The query I posted has small year ranges. In reality, there can be year ranges of 50 years as well. So I guess the 3rd post is not working fine for those cases. Do I need to change anything for that?

Comment: How could this possibly attract a negative downvote, with a SQL Fiddle and two working solutions?

Comment: @GordonLinoff with a difference of seconds both answers were downvoted, so I guess somebody is in a bad mood.

Comment: I didn't downvote any of these questions. I am thankful to you for the help :)