# SQL insert year wise rows into child table - avoiding duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in my SQL database: Parent and Child Parent's primary key is Child's foreign key - ID. Composite key in Child is ID, Year

I have data in Parent but Child is empty. I need to fill the Child table as mentioned below:

Parent:

```
ID  StartYear  EndYear
1     2016      2020
1     2019      2021
2     2018      2022
```

Child:

```
ID  Year    Factor
1   2016     1
1   2017     1
1   2018     1
1   2019     1
1   2020     1
1   2021     1
2   2018     1
2   2019     1
2   2020     1
2   2021     1
2   2022     1
```

I can use either a query or a procedure to do this.

The problem is similar to [SQL insert year wise rows in child table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385031/sql-insert-year-wise-rows-in-child-table)

But here there can't be duplicate rows in Child (Key is ID, year), while the parent has some overlapping years for a particular ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for the solution. As for the duplicates due to overlapping years, just use `distinct`.

```
; with
rcte as
(
    select [ID], [EndYear], [StartYear] as [Year]
    from   Parent

    union all

    select [ID], [EndYear], [Year] + 1 as [Year]
    from   rcte
    where  [Year] < [EndYear]
)
insert into child ([ID], [Year], [Factor])
select distinct [ID], [Year], 1 as [Factor] 
from   rcte
```

Comment: You do not need the first occurrence of {StartYear] from Parent or rcte.

Comment: I think this is not working for me. The first occurrence of StartYear from parent is needed, if any year between the startYear and EndYear for any ID exists in the Child, that row won't be inserted. Am I sounding right?

Comment: i have already edited the query to remove the `StartYear`.  The `StartYear` in the anchor member of the `rcte` is required as the starting year for the recursive query.